# Why does winapps.InstalledApplication return an installed_location of None for Edge?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapp

## I'm trying to extract file location using winapps but the result is always None

```
 from winapps import *
 name="Microsoft Edge"
 cc=InstalledApplication(name)
 vv=cc.install_location
 print(vv)
```

Comment: `"Microsoft Edger"` or `"Microsoft Edge"`?

Comment: BTW, I would probably figure this out by looking at the source code to the `winapps` library, and determining how it determines installed location. If it's a registry key, for example, does Edge fill that key out? If not, `None` may be legitimate. (Frankly, if Microsoft installs an application as part of the system, and doesn't permit its location to be customized, it seems completely legitimate to not fill in an install location).

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but this doesn't look like the intended usage -- `InstalledApplication` should be instanciated by the library. You might try inspecting the result of `winapps.search_installed('Edge')` or `winapps.list_installed()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried that but library is  too complex

Comment: The [winapps readme](https://github.com/rominf/winapps/blob/master/README.md) shows that an empty `install_location` is common. Windows subsystems have changed over the years and an application built for one type may be emulated on another. Like the "windows on windows" WOW stuff where different windows registry rules for applications try to be compatible with each other.

Comment: ...my guess is that his tool doesn't support all of the registry keys where this info is recorded. it may be worth contacting the developers.